# Command required to copy files from different FTP folders

Tags: cmd.exe

I want to copy several files located in different FTP folders and save them to my d drive (D:\T).

The file names contain the text `samik` - for example:

```
\\172.21.89.222\2oct\hourly\2oct_samik.txt
\\172.21.89.222\3oct\hourly\3oct_samik.txt
\\172.21.89.222\4oct\hourly\4oct_samik.txt
\\172.21.89.222\5oct\hourly\5oct_samik.txt
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

From within your CMD window:
Go to your drive and folder you want to use as the target,
run the flowing:

```
for %i in (2 3 4 5 6) do copy \\172.21.89.222\%ioct\hourly\*.txt
```

the for command will loop through copying files from multiple folders.
the (2 3 4 5 6) is the variable that will be appended to each folder.
the copy command will use the current folder if no destination is specified.

Hope this helps. let me know if you need more clarity.